# Django - Static file not found

Tags: django, static-files

I've seen several posts for this issue but didn't found my solution.

I'm trying to serve static files within my Django 1.3 development environment.

Here are my settings

```
...
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/glide/Documents/django/cbox/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  '/static/',
)
...
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
  url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root', settings.STATIC_ROOT}
  ),
...
);
```

My */home/glide/Documents/django/cbox/static/* directory is like

```
css
  main.css
javascript
image
```

I get a 404 error when trying to access *http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/main.css*.

Do I have to specify patterns for css, javascript and images individually ?

Comment: One tip people might find helpful - Django will not serve static content (i.e. CSS changes) when Debug is False

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I confused **STATIC_ROOT** and **STATICFILES_DIRS**

Actually I was not really understanding the utility of **STATIC_ROOT**. I thought that it was the directory on which I have to put my common files. This directory is used for the production, this is the directory on which static files will be put (collected) by [collectstatic](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic).

**STATICFILES_DIRS** is the one that I need.

Since I'm in a development environment, the solution for me is to not use **STATIC_ROOT** (or to specify another path) and set my common files directory in **STATICFILES_DIRS**:

```
#STATIC_ROOT = (os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static_files/'))
import os
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/'),
)
```

Also don't forget to `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: No the __urls.py__ should be like in the question (same thing for media) and don't forget to `from django.conf import settings` of course

Comment: I just want to add to this answer, don't miss the s. it should be STATICFILES_DIRS. I did STATICFILE_DIRS, made me crazy for 45 minutes looking for the error.

Comment: I use `BASE_DIR` built-in const instead of `SITE_ROOT` and it works.

Comment: For django 4 the settings are calles STATIC_DIRS and STATICFILES_DIRS. The latter is the one pointing to the static files for development - it is not in settings.py by default.

Answer (score 60):

There could be only two things in `settings.py` which causes problems for you.

1) `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

2)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

and your static files should lie under static directory which is in same directory as project's settings file.

Even then if your static files are not loading then reason is , you might have kept

```
DEBUG = False
```

change it to True (strictly for development only). In production just change `STATICFILES_DIRS` to whatever path where static files resides.

Comment: In my case it was my environment variable for debug was false. I set it to true and now its working

Comment: Hi..I tried all the mentioned solutions but it still gives me 404. Can someone help with it please ?

Comment: @Naren Yellavula  Why is it working for DEBUG = True?

Comment: I dont know why yet BUT the dist folder not found also when use that until I add 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfile')

Answer (score 44):

Serving static files can be achieved in several ways; here are my notes to self:

- add a `static/my_app/` directory to `my_app` (see the note about namespacing below)
- define a new top level directory and add that to STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py (note that `The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting`)

I prefer the first way, and a setup that's close to the way [defined in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project), so in order to serve the file `admin-custom.css` to override a couple of admin styles, I have a setup like so:

```bash
.
├── my_app/
│   ├── static/
│   │   └── my_app/
│   │       └── admin-custom.css
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── static/
├── templates/
│   └── admin/
│       └── base.html
└── manage.py
```

```py
# settings.py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This is then used in the template like so:

```
# /templates/admin/base.html
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "my_app/admin-custom.css" %}">
{% endblock %}
```

> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles [ed: installed by default], this will be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True [...]
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

When deploying, I run `collectstatic` and serve static files with nginx.

---

The docs which cleared up all the confusion for me:

> ### STATIC_ROOT
>
> The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.
>
> ...it is **not** a place to store your static files permanently. You should do that in directories that will be found by staticfiles’s finders, which by default, are 'static/' app sub-directories and any directories you include in STATICFILES_DIRS).
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#static-root

---

> ### Static file namespacing
>
> Now we might be able to get away with putting our static files directly in my_app/static/ (rather than creating another my_app subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will use the first static file it finds whose name matches, and if you had a static file with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those static files inside another directory named for the application itself.
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

---

> ### STATICFILES_DIRS
>
> Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings file where Django will also look for static files.
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

Comment: Using the `my_app/static/my_app` - approach, adding the line `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` in the `settings.py` made the difference for me. Now, the files are found correctly. My use-case was binding my CV to my personal portfolio webpage like so (in the home.html): `<a href="{% static 'portfolio/CV_Andreas_Luckert.pdf' %}">CV</a>` where `"portfolio" == my_app`

Answer (score 15):

If your static URL is correct but still:

> Not found: /static/css/main.css

Perhaps your WSGI problem.

*➡ Config WSGI serves both development env and production env*

```
==========================project/project/wsgi.py==========================

import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
if settings.DEBUG:
    application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
else:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: For me this I was using WSGI and publishing using gunicorn. This helped me.. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

1. You can remove the `STATIC_ROOT` line
2. Or you can create another `static` folder in different directory. For suppose the directory is: `project\static`
   Now update:

```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/static/')
    ]
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Whatever you do the main point is `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT` should not contain same directory.

*I know it's been a long time but hope the new buddies can get help from it*

Answer (score 6):

`STATICFILES_DIRS`  is used in **development** and `STATIC_ROOT` in **production**,

`STATICFILES_DIRS`  and `STATIC_ROOT` should not have same folder name,

If you need to use the exact same static folder in development and production, try this method

include this in  `settings.py`

```
import socket

HOSTNAME = socket.gethostname()

# if hostname same as production url name use STATIC_ROOT 
if HOSTNAME == 'www.example.com':
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
        ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another error can be not having your app listed in the `INSTALLED_APPS` listing like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'your_app',
]
```

Without having it in, you can face problems like not detecting your static files, basically all the files involving your app. Even though it can be correct as suggested in the correct answer by using:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (adding/path/of/your/app)
```

Can be one of the errors and should be reviewed if getting this error.

Answer (score 4):

In your cmd type command
`python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 static`
It will give the directory in which Django is looking for static files.If you have created a virtual environment then there will be a static folder inside this virtual_environment_name folder.
`VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT_NAME\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static`.
On running the above 'findstatic' command if Django shows you this path then just paste all your static files in this static directory.
In your html file use JINJA syntax for href and check for other inline css. If still there is an image src or url after giving JINJA syntax then prepend it with '/static'.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I solve this problem by adding my project name in INSTALLED_APPS.[image]

Comment: this fixed it for me but I think I might need a better solution each app should have its own static folder in my case

Answer (score 2):

```
TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS=[STATIC_DIR]
```

Answer (score 2):

Always remember two things in Django at the end of file `settings.py`

For development

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

For production

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
```

Since you are working in a development environment, comment out the other two paths from `settings.py` file

```
#STATIC_ROOT = '/home/glide/Documents/django/cbox/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#  '/static/',
#)
```

And for the `urls.py` make changes as follows

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
  url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root', settings.STATIC_URL}
  ),
...
);
```

Hope this may solve the problems

Answer (score 2):

Django does not have a built-in solution for serving static files, at least not in **production** when DEBUG has to be False.

We have to use a **third-party** solution to accomplish this.

To install WhiteNoise in your virtual environment, type the command below:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

then Modify Settings

To make Django aware of you wanting to run WhitNoise, you have to specify it in the MIDDLEWARE list in settings.py file:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
].
```

Comment: you need add the whitenoise middleware after exactly security one, see docs https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#enable-whitenoise

Answer (score 2):

If you are on development environment you will need to define `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIR` and if you are on production environment you need to define `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`

For windows:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

And for linux environment

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
     STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static'),)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that I moved my `DEBUG` setting in my local settings to be overwritten by a default `False` value. Essentially look to make sure the DEBUG setting is actually false if you are developing with `DEBUG` and `runserver`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've have added the `django-storages` module (to support uploading files to S3 in your django app for instance), and if like me you did not read correctly [the documentation of this module](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html), just remove this line from your `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Otherwise it will cause your static assets to be looked NOT on your local machine but remotely in the S3 bucket, including admin panel CSS, and thus effectively breaking admin panel CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need only for Development:

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles'),
)
```

For Production (when using /manage.py collectstatic):

```
STATIC_ROOT  =   os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

After Debug = False your static files will not loading. You can check it via entering to 127.0.0.1:8000/staticfiles/css/main.css (for example).
So, you need change to Debug = True and then reload the page via Ctrl+F5.