# Django - putting static files inside app folder

Tags: django

I've started an django app in an existing project and I'm trying to follow the project's pattern to organize stuff. In other apps I see that the static files are in the app itself, eg: 
File path: `appname/static/js/file.js`
Javascript, inside the template: `<script src="{% static 'js/file.js' %}"></script>`

This works in other apps. I'm trying to do the same but the rendered file url gives me a 404 error.

What should I be checking to make it work? I've looked in the settings file, but there is nothing special there nor in the urls.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What does the error message on the page display, given that you have set `DEBUG=True` in the settings file?

Comment: 'js/file.js' could not be found

Comment: Well, this should't return a 404 error, are you sure there are not any other error messages. Could you give all the details given when you get a 404?

Comment: Have you added your app to installed apps in the settings?

Comment: @mart0903 
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8001/static/file.js
Raised by:  django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve

'js/file.js' could not be found

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: Have you added your app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: Also, check this question. I suspect this might be the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014663/django-static-file-not-found

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The path `appname/static/` is the default that Django will look for in every installed app, no `settings` needed. Make sure your new app is actually listed in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

Since you are on the development server, maybe you are missing the static file URLs. Make sure this is at the end of `urls.py`:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

That adds URL path `/static/` for all files in any `appname/static/`.

Also, if you have more directories (not appname/static/) that you want to map to a URL path when using the development server, you could add then with `static()` like this

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static('/pics/', document_root=/var/www/pictures/)
```

Comment: Okay, the truth is.  The static files in an app folder must go under /appname/static/appname/img/myimage.png e.g. if you address them as 'appname/img/myimage.png'.  Only took me a few hours to figure that out.  Thanks Django for your weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have static folder in each app but `/static/media` in the template was not picking image from that app throwing 404 .

And the thing that I had done initially was I have put `static_url = "/static/"` in settings.py and in django docs they have mentioned to put `"static/"` and when I made this change it was working correctly

django_doc = https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/