# Django static file not found 1.11

Tags: django-1.11, weasyprint

I've read this:
[Django - Static file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014663/django-static-file-not-found)

but I'm still confused since one of my project's app's static files are being served. I think the problem lies in a django-weasyprint setting:

settings.py

```
>>> settings.BASE_DIR
'/Users/blakepowell/django_/direct2'
>>> settings.STATIC_ROOT
'/static/'
>>> settings.BASE_DIR
'/Users/blakepowell/django_/direct2'
>>> settings.DJANGO_ROOT
'/Users/blakepowell/django_/direct2'
>>> settings.STATICFILES_DIRS
['/Users/blakepowell/django_/direct2/flights/static/', '/Users/blakepowell/django_/direct2/pdf_output/static/']
```

pdf_output/views.py per [django-weasyprint](https://github.com/fdemmer/django-weasyprint)

```
class PrintView(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, PDFView):
    # None
    pdf_stylesheets = [
    settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'pdf_output/static/pdf_output/css/pdf_output.css',
    ]
```

error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/pdf_output/static/pdf_output/css/pdf_output.css'
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py you have

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/Users/blakepowell/django_/direct2/flights/static/',
    '/Users/blakepowell/django_/direct2/pdf_output/static/'
]
```

I think?
Now you can access the files in these directorys diretly via `/static/` :

```
class PrintView(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, PDFView):
    # None
    pdf_stylesheets = [
        '/static/pdf_output/css/pdf_output.css',
    ]
```

if your css file is under `/Users/blakepowell/django_/direct2/pdf_output/static/pdf_output/css/pdf_output.css`

or via

```
class PrintView(WeasyTemplateResponseMixin, PDFView):
    # None
    pdf_stylesheets = [
        '/static/css/pdf_output.css',
    ]
```

if your css file is under `/Users/blakepowell/django_/direct2/pdf_output/static/css/pdf_output.css`

I can not see where your css file is located on your machine. Why are you using two 'static' folders?