# How to make django look for static in specified directories instead of view/file.css

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I am aware that similar question was answered in [Django - Static file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014663/django-static-file-not-found)
But looks like I miss something or it was, somehow, a different case.

I have my static folders set in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
    ]
```

And in the code, I refer to file like

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link href="{% static 'filename.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Still, django searches for this file in /view/filename.css
How do I make it work?
P.S. Also bootstrap.css
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="hash" crossorigin="anonymous">`
isn't loaded for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have django.contrib.staticfiles included in your INSTALLED_APPS ? What django version are you using? 
If you just debug your app, you must set setting DEBUG=True to allow django serve your static files.

Comment: I am using Django 2.1.4
Yes, I have added django.contrib.staticfiles into ISTALLED_APPS

Comment: DEBUG=True setted?

Comment: Yes, it is set.

Comment: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/") and {% static 'filename.css' %} means, that path to your static file must be BASE_DIR/static/filename.css . Is it there? No subfolders? BASE_DIR setted correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is directly in static. BASE_DIR is set to os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Comment: Please, share browser logs and path in  BASE_DIR variable

Comment: localhost/:13 GET http://localhost:8000/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:21 GET http://localhost:8000/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:16 GET http://localhost:8000/view/filename.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
BaseDir = /home/user/PycharmProjects/ProjectName

Comment: 'view' is name of your application? Try move static folder in ProjectName/view/static

Comment: View is the name of one of my views (method in Project/App/view.py)
Just tried, but still to no result((

Comment: Okay, try move it in Project/App/static folder. Django by default trying to search static files in two ways: in folders, listed in STATICFILES_DIRS, and in 'static' folder in applications directories. It must find static file in static subfolder of your application.

Comment: And also try to replace {% load staticfiles %} with {% load static %}

Comment: Didn't work either. Also, why does it try to look for bootstrap files in /dist/css/bootstrap.min.css those files are not even in my project's folder?

Comment: it is not normal, maybe your html page contains this call somewhere else? Maybe it's wrong template called in view file?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Turned out I had another method with the same name in my views.

Answer (score 1):

A path to 'static' folder, if you create project like this: ***django-admin startproject myproject_root***, should be: "***myproject_root/myproject/static***"

```
# settings.py
DEBUG=True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Hi, it must work, if you haven't solved this problem yet, post here structure of your project directory with "static" folder and part of settings.py file with paths to the static folder and I'll try to help you.