# Django : Page Not Found when trying to access static files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I know there are already several threads on the topic. I've been through most of them (especially all the troubleshooting listed in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014663/django-static-file-not-found)) but I can't figure out my issue.

I am trying to use a Bootstrap template in my Django project, and I'd like to simply start by accessing the files in the `/static/` directory. My project directory looks like this :

[image]

Whenever I try to load the page `http://localhost:8000/static/theme/assets/css/style.css` it returns a `Page not found` error (and obviously no CSS/JS content appears on my index).

Here are my settings:

- I have `debug = True`
- `ÌNSTALLED_APPS` contains `django.contrib.staticfiles`
- settings.py looks like this :

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),)
```

But I still can't access anything from the /static/ directory.
I tried to access the CSS and JS files in base.html this way :

```
{% load static %}
...
<link href="{% static 'theme/assets/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I really have no clue how I could solve this.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Is `base.html` properly bound bound with a URL and with a view function via a URL dispatcher ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/ ) ? Can you access that file from your browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Is `base.html` properly bound to a URL and to a view function via a [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/) ? Can you access that file from your browser ?

If yes, try to substitute this line

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),)
```

with this one

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Comment: Well, `index.html` is bound to a URL thanks to `path("", views.index, name="index")` and `base.html` is called inside `index.html` with `{% extends 'base.html' %}`. And I had tried removing the / but no effect sadly

Comment: try to put an image in a folder `img` inside `static`, espose it in your `base.html` with `<img src="{% static 'img/<my_image_name>.<image_extention>' %}">` and see if it appears in your browser

Comment: try to inspect the console logs of your browser