# Django can't find css files

Tags: html, css, django

my django can't link my css to my html template. I've implemented almost every solution i could find, added some recommended url patterns, tried full paths instead of relative, ensured i had things set up correctly from the official docs, but can't find what I'm missing.

My settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

file path: `BASE_DIR/static/css/main.css`

store.html:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css" />

<h3>Store</h3>
```

errors:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

> GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - Static file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014663/django-static-file-not-found)

Comment: No but I just made a new project

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this format to use static in your django template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" />
```

**If this doesn't work:**
In your Django project's urls.py file, make sure you have configured the static view to serve static files during development. Add the following import at the top of your urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

....

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

If still does not work then either
Try placing the static folder into templates folder/app folder.

**or**

**RECOMMENDED** Try printing **BASE_DIR** variable now check if your static folder exists in the BASE_DIR path.

Comment: I already tried and tried once more using static in my template instead of the full path. I had also added the same url pattern you provided but it doesn't work

Comment: I've added two more ways. Check if any of two works...

Comment: I've done so and the base directory is indeed correct, and my static exists in my base dir.
I've created a new project and everything works well. I'm trying to see what difference I'm making in the old one and the new one but i can't see any difference as far as the folder structure and settings go. I'll just leave it be, thanks a lot for the helo

Answer (score 0):

you should also define static root in settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

and in urls like what Proud Wadhwa said write this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: I had done that. And I tried making a new project and the css was served without any issues even without the urlpattern. I don't know what the issue was with the previous setup since I'm using the same configurations and the new one works now. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

So this is a weird fix. But apparently renaming or recreating my css folder solved it.

It's almost as if my django hadn't recognized or wasn't treating it as a css folder before and renaming it fixed that. (I used the same exact name as before; css)

[image: Before]

[image: After]